# How to add different vectors in vector class? Python

Tags: python

This is one of my first python programs.
I cannot operate on vectors created from init with  fill_n. I don't know what I should change.

additionally
"The inner representation of the vector should not be visible outside the class (protected field)."

```
class Vector:
    def __init__ (self, lista):
        self.value = lista

    def __add__ (self, other):

        res = Vector( [x + y for x, y in zip(self.value, other.value) ])
        return res

    def __mul__(self, other):
        dot=0
        for x, y in zip(self.value, other.value):
             dot = dot + x *y
        return dot

    def fill_n ( size, val):
        value=[val]*size
        return tuple(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join([str(x) for x in self.value])


def main():
    v1 = Vector([1, 2, 3])
    v2 = Vector([4, 2, 2])
    v3 = Vector.fill_n(3,1)

    print (v1 + v2)
    print (v1 + v3) #It doesn't work 
    print(v3)


main()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 34, in <module>
    main()
  line 30, in main
    print (v1 + v3) #It doesn't work
  line 7, in __add__
    res = Vector( [x + y for x, y in zip(self.value, other.value) ])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: `fill_n` returns a `tuple`, not a `Vector`, and the `__add__` method does not seem to handle the case where you're adding a `tuple` to a `Vector`.

Comment: Also, `fill_n` is not defined as a `@staticmethod`, meaning that the `size` parameter is actually being treated like a `self` parameter. If you use any decent IDE it will highlight this issue right away. If you're not using an IDE I highly recommend getting one. PyCharm is free and works great.

Comment: Your code produced an error but you didn't put it in your post; I put it in there just for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill_n` is clearly *intended* to make a `Vector`, but as implemented, does nothing of the sort, so you get type conflicts. Make it an alternate constructor with `@classmethod`, and you'll get the results you want with no other changes:

```
@classmethod                 # Ensures it passes the class even when called on an instance
def fill_n(cls, size, val):  # Added initial parameter, cls, the actually class called on
    value=[val]*size
    return cls(value)  # Changed from tuple to cls which will be Vector (or a subclass)
```

As a rule, *all* alternate constructors should be `@classmethod`s; with `@staticmethod`, you won't be subclass friendly, with undecorated methods omitting `self`/`cls` it only works when called on the class, not an instance (making it harder to construct new instances from the class of an existing instance), and with instance methods, you *can't* call it on the class.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you only need one change to get this to work; `v3` is a `tuple` of 3 values. You can just pass it to the constructor of `Vector` and the result will be a proper `Vector` object that you can add to other vectors, like so:

```py
v3 = Vector(Vector.fill_n(3,1))
```

Like I said in a comment, the `fill_n` method doesn't reference the `self` parameter, so you should put `@staticmethod` above it. It's not necessary in this case but it'll throw off any kinds of static analyzers or linters that IDEs use:

```py
@staticmethod
    def fill_n(size, val):
        ...
```

With that taken care of, your script runs fine. Output:

```
5, 4, 5
2, 3, 4
1, 1, 1
```

Comment: A class method would be more appropriate than a static method. `def fill_n(cls, size, n): return cls(...)`, where the same list you would pass directly to `Vector` should be constructed from `size` and `n` to pass to `cls`.